# How to calculate 15! without using calculator

Tags: contest-math, factorial

I am joining a maths competition and recently I am preparing for it. I came across a question that asks me to fill the blank of a number:

> 1_0767436_000

And this number is the product of $15!= 15\times 14\times 13\times 12...\times 1$.

The competition doesn't allow to use a calculator, so I am wondering how to multiply these without calculator. 
Can I have a solution that can solve a similar question and also the solution to this question? 
Tqvm

Comment: "solution that can solve similar question" is a very tall order. Questions of this type are highly individual, and there is no one solution to fit all. Especially if this is for a competition, where problems are usually explicitly constructed to not be too similar to earlier problems. What does help, though, is lots of experience and a healthy "try a bunch of things" attitude. So, with that in mind, have you tried a bunch of things? What did you try? How did it go?

Comment: Are there two blanks there?  Are the two blanks the same value?

Comment: @MichaelBurr - they are in fact not the same value - the second is obviously even and the first will then be different to get all the digits to add up to a multiple of $9$

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163638/finding-missing-digits-in-factorials and https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-the-last-n-digits-of-a-factorial-without-calculating-the-whole-factorial

Answer (score 4):

As the comments above mention, these types of problems are usually ad hoc.  For this one, for example, you can try the following:

Sketch: The lowest nonzero should be easy to calculate via $\mod{10}$ calculations (after dividing out by the three factors of $10$).  Then, for the other number, observe that $15!$ is divisible by $9$ and use a divisiblity test.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x$ and $y$ be the left and right missing digits respectively.  First apply the divisibility test for $9$, which demands that the sum of all digits be divisible by $9$ for $1×2×...×9×...×15$.  Thereby

$x+y\in \{2,11\}$

Now count factors of $2$ and $5$ in the factorial.  There is a factor of $5$ coming from each of $5,10,15$ so three factors of $5$.  There are factors of $2$ coming from $2,4,...,14$, with each multiple of $4$ providing another factor of $2$ and $8$ providing an additional factor beyond those.  Thus $11$ factors of $2$, eight more than the factors of $5$.  So there are only three terminal zeroes and the remaining digits must be divisible by $2^8$, thus the last three digits before the zeroes must be a multiple of $8$.

Both $360$ and $368$ satisfy divisibility by $8$, but there cannot be a fourth terminal zero so $y=8$ forcing $x=11-8=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually math competitions are about ideas rather than calculations.
I would be surprised if calculating 15! would be non-avoidable. It might be that considering properties of 15! Is helpful for some problems and when this is the case considering prime factors is usually a good idea.
I recommend to read about Legendre’s Formula.

Answer (score 0):

We assume that before entering the contest we've become an 'expert' at modulo $11$ calculations, so that we 'know' (or can quickly calculate) the following:

$\quad 5! \equiv 10 \pmod{11}$
$\quad 6! \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$
$\quad 7! \equiv 2 \pmod{11}$
$\quad 8! \equiv 5 \pmod{11}$
$\quad 9! \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$
$\quad 10! \equiv 10 \pmod{11}$

Problem: Find $a$ and $b$ where $15! = 1a0767436b000$.

For the problem at hand we don't need these shortcuts, since

$\quad 15! \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$

You first solve for $b$ in the manner suggested by Michael Burr, and then write out

$\tag 1 15! =  1a07674368000$

Although in this problem there are exactly three $0's$ to the right of $b$ and it  to easy to factor out $10^3$, there are more complicated variations on these contest problems. In the $2^{nd}$ section of this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3803410/432081) a general method for finding that 'far right digit' $b$ by using modulo $10^5$ calculations is given; the *contest tactic* of using the fact that $10! \equiv 28800 \pmod{10^5}$ can be the starting line of attack for these problems.

Applying $(\text{mod } 11)$ to $\text{(1)}$ we can use the *alternating sum of the digits* technique,

$\quad 0 \equiv 0 - 0 + 0 - 8 + 6 - 3 + 4 - 7 + 6 - 7 + 0 - a + 1 \equiv -a -8 \pmod{11}$

and we conclude that $a = 3$,

$\tag{ANS.} 15! = 1307674368000$

---

**'Contest' Theory**

Let $n$ be any integer and let the expansion, $R$, of $n!$ be given with exactly one digit, $a$ missing. Let $p$ be any prime number greater than or equal to $11$. Then by applying $\text{mod } p$ to

$\quad n! = R$

you can solve for $a \text{ modulo } p$.

Since $0 \le a \le 9$, the modulo solution will be a 'spot on' solution.

Fortunately, there is no need to stray away from $p=11$ for these problems.